# Value cannot be send to database

Tags: android, json, radio-button

For my application, while registering, user must choose gender by using the radio button(RadioGroup)

After they choose it and fill up the register form, all data including gender should be store into phpmyAdmin.

And I have to store as a string the value for RadioButton.

Unfortunately, all the data are not be send and even after I click the send button nothing happen.

```
    package com.example.prime.try;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.sql.Struct;


public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroupGender;
    private RadioButton radioButtonGender;
    private String userGender = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final TextView tvGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
        final EditText etNationality = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNationality);
        final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        final RadioGroup radioGroupGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupGender);
        final RadioButton rbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
        final RadioButton rbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);
        final Button bSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);


        final int selectedId = radioGroupGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButtonGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        //final String userGender = Integer.toString(radioButtonGender.getId());
        //final String userGender = radioButtonGender.getText().toString();
        //final String userGender = String.valueOf(radioButtonGender.getId());

        //final String userGender = {((RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroupGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString()};


        bSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
                final String nationality = etNationality.getText().toString();
                final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                //Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                                //Register.this.startActivity(intent);


                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };


                radioGroupGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup radioGroupGender,int checkedId){
                        int id = radioGroupGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);

                        String userGender = rb.getText().toString();

                    }
                });



                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, age, userGender, nationality, email, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }


    public String RadioButtonClicked(View view) {

        String userGender = "";
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rbFemale:
                if (checked)
                    userGender = "Female";
                break;
            case R.id.rbMale:
                if (checked)
                    userGender = "Male";
                break;
        }
        return userGender;
    }

}
```

And this is the php file, thank you for your help in advance :)

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("bio.000webhostapp.com", "anonymous12345", "animals89", "testing1235");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $Gend = $_POST["userGender"];
    $nationality = $_POST["nationality"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];


    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, Gend, nationality, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $name, $age, $Gend, $nationality, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Comment: Is your `000webhostapp` a free plan?  If so, the `$con` is not succeeding because 000webhost says: **remote connections are not available on free plans**.

Comment: @PaulT. yes, I'm using a free plan. Can you elaborate more about 'remote connections are not available on free plans'?

Comment: I have a free site with them too, and discovered the same when I tried to do some remote connections to the DB. Their own [FAQ](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-my-computer-27) states this fact. Which means, if you upgrade from free to a more premium level (a paid account), then it appears that remote DB connections can be available. Otherwise, you can only use the DB by your site from their hosting because `localhost` is used as the first parameter to `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: okay, thank you for your help. :)